# How to have tox ignore setup.cfg install paths?

Tags: python, tox

I have a simple `tox.ini` like this:

```
[tox]
envlist = py37

[testenv]
deps =
    pytest
commands =
    pytest
```

But when I run `tox` I get an error like this:

```
Installing collected packages: zipp, typing-extensions, pyparsing, importlib-metadata, toml, py, pluggy, packaging, iniconfig, attrs, pytest
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/mypackage'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

That's because my `setup.cfg` contains:

```
[install]
install-scripts = /usr/bin/mypackage/modules/
```

How can I make `tox` ignore this path so that it installs `pytest` in a reasonable location?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe if you added a `pyproject.toml` right next to `setup.cfg` to trigger the "build isolation" it would help. There is an example [here in _setuptools_ doc](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html?highlight=pyproject#setup-cfg-only-projects).

Comment: Thanks @sinoroc Maybe this is a good reason to figure out `pyproject.toml`.

Comment: Really no guarantee. What you have here is quite unusual, I have no clue how to handle this.

Comment: Haven't really been able to test this idea yet, but after more reading I am not hopeful. I believe the build isolation is with regards to building my package. That part actually succeeds. It's installing the `pytest` dep that fails. Since this command is executed from `toxinidir` (https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/3.20.1/config.html) `pip` will read the `setup.cfg` parameters and try to install `pytest` to the wrong place. It seems crazy to me that pip will read a local `setup.cfg` when trying to install a totally unrelated package...

Comment: Here's another example of this type of problem: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/python-setup-cfg-wrongly-applied-to-all-python-package-dependencies/1097

Comment: Hmm. Maybe this is fixed in a later tox version. I think I have this particular issue resolved by uninstalling the debian tox and instead getting the latest version via pip.